# How to load test MongoDB using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, database, stress-testing

I want to load test MongoDb using JMeter, but apparently MongoDB Source Config and MongoDB Script have been deprecated. Please let me know how to load test MongoDB with detailed step by step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
not_in_menu=
```

This way you will get "deprecated" elements including [MongoDB Source Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Source_Config_(DEPRECATED)) and [MongoDB Script](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Script_(DEPRECATED)) back.

Be aware that it is better to use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) for MongoDB load testing as MongoDB Script has some performance problems. See [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) article for more details.